# Some lyrics that need a little correction!

Tags: lyrics

"throw it (food?) to the monsters for them to share"

I want it to mean that you throw food to some whatever monsters, so they could share it with each other. Is it possible to correct this sentence, so that "share" remains as the last word?

Could someone help me with this? I just want the sentence to make sense, I'm not here to spellcheck, this is not for a test, this is for myself who is more laid back about spelling.